# how to append a break after 7th word of aparagraph in php

Tags: php

I wish to display paragraphs in html table,incase the paragraph has more than 7 words,then it must have aline break and the text must come in next line of the column,
Can some one suggest ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: something using str_word_count() and I  need to append <br> in the variable storing the paragraph details in case paragraph has more than 7 words

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/* read and print characters, while incrementing "$counter"  then include this condition in your loop */

if($counter % 7 == 0)
{
 $counter = 0;
 echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$array=str_word_count($msg,1);
$i=0;
foreach($array as $ar)
 {
       echo $ar.' ';
       $i++;
       if($i==7)
       {
           echo '<br>';  
           $i=0;
        }
}
```